# changing color of body text on MediaWiki's "common.css" has no effect

Tags: mediawiki

Over at the MediaWiki.org page [Manual:CSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS), it mentions:

> If you want to make all text on the wiki green you can add the code
>   `body { color: green; }` to MediaWiki:Common.css.

I've made a few successful global changes to my wiki (running 1.26.2) through [its common.css](http://stevenarntson.com/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css) page, but making the one above doesn't work. Text remains black, even when looked at from another browser. I'd like to find out what I'm doing wrong because I'd ultimately like to change the font for the site to "Georgia," and I've also failed to make that happen.

Here's some of the code that's presently on my common.css page. The first two lines (hiding the "powered by" icon) seem to work. The second two (turning the text green) don't.

```
/* hiding "powered by MediaWiki" icon */
#footer-poweredbyico { display: none; }

/* trying to turn the wiki text green */
body { color: green; }
```

Comment: are you sure you've done it correctly? can you post what you've tried, maybe we can help you.

Comment: Thank you---I've edited the question above to add those lines.

Comment: Make sure the browser is not picking the older version of common.css from the cache or the rule been overridden by some other rule later. You can use developer tools in chrome to check from where the color of the body is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS-directive `body { color: green; }` is overwritten by directive on `.mw-body { color: #252525; }`.

If you really want green copy-text use: `.mw-body { color: green; }`;)

But changing the font-family is possible on the body tag with `body { font-family: Georgia; }` (except the headings)

PS: I changed the example on [mediawiki.org Manual:CSS](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS)

Comment: Perfect! Success. Thank you so much for your answer as I struggle through the learning curve here.